# Thread1: Exc_Bad_Instruction

Tags: swift, error-handling

I can't figure out why am I keep getting this Thread:
Error message when running this program.
I'm new to programming and trying an exercise and keep getting this error message.

Also I was trying to figure out how to resize the pictures to fit on the screen.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var memberChoice: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBAction func getMember(sender:AnyObject){
        var member: String =
    memberChoice.titleForSegmentAtIndex(memberChoice.selectedSegmentIndex)!
        var imageURLString: String!

        if member  == "Daddy" {
            imageURLString = "file: ///Users/natashamays/Desktop/Daddy.jpg"
        }

        else if member == "Tasha" {
            imageURLString = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-2c_GDVdcAFk/UBR7auHIHrI/AAAAAAAAEW8/gJ3F-MVUpL4/w140-h139-p/3.jpg"
        }

        else if member == "Jasmin" {
            imageURLString = "file:///Users/natashamays/Desktop/IMG_3879.JPG"
        }

        var imageURL: NSURL = NSURL(string:imageURLString)!
            webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: imageURL))
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Comment: Could you mark which line you are getting the error from?

Comment: var imageURL: NSURL = NSURL(string:imageURLString)!

Comment: sorry hit enter to quickly - but the error message shows up along this line

Comment: You need add more info about your problem, is this an iPhone or Mac app? But an easy one to spot is that your Daddy imageURLString has an space that shouldn't be there.